# Unable To Connect to Some Apple Input Devices/Unable To Delete One Apple KB from BT Settings

Tags: bluetooth

Two issues after installing Juno:

1. Unable To Connect to Some Apple Input Devices;

2.Unable To Delete One Apple wireless keyboard from Bluetooth Settings so that I can try to reconnect it.

Using information found elsewhere on SE I have used terminal to stop and restart bluetooth, then restarted. Same issues.

I have successfully connected to a Magic Mouse [in Juno], and was successful in connecting an Apple Magic Mouse and an Apple wireless keyboard in Loki.

I'm using a late 2009 iMac. (Was using this same machine for Loki.)

Thanks for insights.

Answer (score 1):

2.
in System Settings / Bluetooth
you'll find a "-" option down in the left corner of the window.